# Position of eyes and hair goes wrong after exporting

Tags: export, bones, collada

[image: This is how it looks in blender]

[image: This is how it looks after exporting as collada file]

I'm making a model in Blender and try to export it as *collada* file. This step goes well, but there are problems with the hair, eyes and eyebrows locations. As you see in the picture above the hair, eyes and eyebrows are positioned lower than what they are positioned pre-export.

I've attached the eyes, eyebrows and hair to the head bone and they move well when animating the model. It only happens after I export it. I don't know whether it's wrong to attach them to the top bone.

Answer (score 1):

before exporting you need to set their world orgin to the same as the body orgin.

1)select the body 
2)shift + s "cursor to selection"
3)select one of the other meshes(hair or eyes  or whatever order is not important)
4)shift + ctrl + alt + c(yes a crazy hot key) then select "origin to 3d cursor"
4a) you can alternatively just press space and do a search for "origin" and find it on the list
after that re-export your model...if that does not work, try to apply location, rotation, and scale...by selecting each object and using ctrl+a

I hope that helps, if not...just update here what the outcome was. It will help better diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and I think I found solution. My post is [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163153/after-exporting-to-dae-some-objects-are-shifted).
In my work I had objects parented to the bone. That did cause offset. I also tried different parent types like object or armature, but it created other issues. So my solution is parent it with automatic weight.